# seaborn tsplot: legend colors are faded

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In my seaborn `tsplot` the colors don't match the lines drawn:

[image: Colors don't match the lines drawn.]

```
for item in item_list:
    sns.tsplot(get_data(), color=get_color(), legend=True)

sns.plt.legend(labels=item_list)
sns.plt.show()
```

I read the sns.tsplot and plt.legend documentation pages and can't think why this is happening.

Comment: What do your `get_data` and `get_color` functions do?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help if you are keeping your method for specifying the colors secret?

Comment: @ArcturusB
get_data returns a list of floats
get_color returns a random hex color string

Comment: Right, could you edit your answer to add these please?

Comment: @skend in my answer below you see that I just invented some functions to use in the code in order to produce a [mcve]. Such a [mcve] is what people here asked you for and should already be present in the question from the beginning, such that the code can be copied and run to reproduce the issue. Would be good to remember that next time asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tsplot` adds some regions with low alpha around the lines. Even if they are not visible (because a single line is plotted) they find their way into the legend.

A workaround is to get the lines from the plot directly:

```
h = plt.gca().get_lines()
plt.legend(handles=h, labels=item_list)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

item_list = list("ABXY")

get_data = lambda : np.random.rand(10)
get_color = lambda : "#" + "".join(np.random.choice(list("02468acef"), size=6))

for item in item_list:
    sns.tsplot(get_data(), color=get_color())

h = plt.gca().get_lines()
plt.legend(handles=h, labels=item_list)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Let me just mention that there seems to be no reason to use a `tsplot` anyways in this case. A simple line plot (`plt.plot`) is sufficient and has less potential of confusion. The blow code produces exactly the same output as the above.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

item_list = list("ABXY")

get_data = lambda : np.random.rand(10)
get_color = lambda : "#" + "".join(np.random.choice(list("02468acef"), size=6))

for item in item_list:
    plt.plot(get_data(), color=get_color(), label=item)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just updated the answer to use a `plt.plot`, which might be less confusing.